# Sqlite statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Eclipse log complains:

> Failure 1 (near "(": syntax error)

My statement is as follows:

```
String sql = "UPDATE History 
                 SET Latitude = '" + latitude + 
                 "', Longitude = '" + longitude + 
                 "', Altitude = '" + altitude +
                 "', Address = '" + address + 
                 "', Title = '" + title +
                 "', Remarks = '" + remarks +
                 "', strftime('%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M:%S', 'now', 'localtime') 
               WHERE _id = '" + lastID +"'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string value from the `strftime` function.  You're not saving it as anything, and that's not legal in a UPDATE statement.  You're probably missing

`CurrentTime = strftime(...`

Comment: you can just say something like "updatedAt = now()" that should work in sqlite.

Comment: @bdares Thanks! How careless of me to forget the column name....Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Matthew Rudy Thanks but I need the Strftime instead of now(). The issue has been resolve :)